# Laravel API using JWT Auth Credential (username/email)

Tags: laravel, jwt

I'm using laravel with JWT Auth to connect my laravel project to mobile, this is my api controller at laravel

```
public function login(Request $request) {
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    try {
        // attempt to verify the credentials and create a token for the user
        if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
        }
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        // something went wrong whilst attempting to encode the token
        return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
    }

    // all good so return the token
    $user = Sentry::authenticate($credentials, false);

    return response()->json([
        'code' => '200',
        'message' => 'success',
        'last_updated' => $user->updated_at->format("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z"),
        'data' => [
            'id' => $user->id,
            'first_name' => $user->first_name,
            'last_name' => $user->last_name,
            'email' => $user->email,
            'username' => $user->username,
            'token' => $token
        ]
    ]);
}
```

but how to set the credentials using email or username with this JWT?

Comment: http://rjv.im/post/78940780589/api-token-authentication-with-laravel-and-sentry might help you.

Comment: Did you figure it out>

Comment: @Albert yes, i'm figure it out

Comment: @yudijohn how you did it ..please share ..i need it !

Comment: @yudijohn how did you achieve this?

Comment: I hope you are using `"tymon/jwt-auth"` package.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `"tymon/jwt-auth"` package, then you can just pass the `user` object to the `JWTAuth` class and bam!, you can get the `JWT` token in return which you can use to make user go through the app.

```
$user = User::where('email', $email)
->orWhere('username', $username)
->first();

$token = null;
if (!$token = JWTAuth::fromUser($get_info)) {
   return $this->respondInternalError( 'Can\'t generate the JWT token right now, try again later!', 'object', 400);
}

return response()->json([
    'code' => '200',
    'message' => 'success',
    'last_updated' => $user->updated_at->format("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z"),
    'data' => [
        'id' => $user->id,
        'first_name' => $user->first_name,
        'last_name' => $user->last_name,
        'email' => $user->email,
        'username' => $user->username,
        'token' => $token
    ]
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can login using email or using the following format

```php
public function login(Request $request)
    {
          //validate incoming request
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email_phone' => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ]);

        try {

            $login_type = filter_var( $request->email_phone, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) ? 'email' : 'phone';

            // return $login_type;

            $credentials = [$login_type => $request->email_phone, 'password'=>$request->password];

            if (! $token = Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json($this->customResponse("failed", "Unauthorized"), 401);
            }

            return $this->respondWithToken($token);
        } catch(JWTException $e) {

            return response()->json($this->customResponse("failed", "An error occured, please contact support.", $user), 500);

        }
    }
```